# Is there anything in Jewish texts says Israel must be theocratic?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kohen-priest, malchut-royalty

Is there anything in Jewish texts says Israel must be theocratic?

Answer (score 1):

The Bible lays out a very clear and detailed description for the laws of society and government. See from [Deuteronomy 16:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.16.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and on. Here are some highlights from [Deuteronomy 17:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.8-20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) and onwards:

> If a matter of law is too abstruse for you—between blood and blood, between decision and decision, or between leprosy [a plague of confinement] and leprosy [a plague of confinement], matters under [legal] dispute in your city; you shall rise and ascend to the place that Adonoy, your God, will have chosen.
> 9You are to come before the kohanim-the Levites and the judge officiating during those days; you will inquire and they will tell you the legal decision.
> 10You are to act according to the word that they tell you from that place that Adonoy will have chosen; and you are to be careful to fulfill exactly as they instruct you.
> 11In accord with the Torah that they instruct you and upon the law that they state to you, are you to act; do not deviate from the word they tell you, neither right or left.
> 12But the man who acts deliberately to not heed the kohein who stands to serve there [before] Adonoy, your God, or the judge; that man is to be executed and you will eliminate the evil [doer] from Yisroel.
> 13Let all the people hear and fear, and not sin deliberately again.
> 14When you arrive in the land that Adonoy, your God, is giving you and inherit it and live in it, and you say, ‘‘Let me appoint over me a king like all the nations around me;’’
> 15Appoint are you to appoint over yourself a king whom Adonoy, your God, will choose. From among your brothers are you to appoint over yourself a king; you may not [you have no permission to] place over yourself a foreigner who is not your brother.
> 16However, he must not aquire an abundance of horses for himself so that he will not return the people to Egypt in order to aquire an abundance of horses, because Adonoy told you, ‘‘You are not to proceed to return along this route again.’’
> 17And he is not to aquire an abundance of wives for himself so that his heart will not veer; and silver and gold he may not accumulate for himself in great abundance.
> 18It shall be, that when he occupies the throne of his kingdom, he must write for himself a duplicate of this Torah in a scroll form [the scroll] before the kohanim—the Levites.
> 19It is to accompany him and he is to read in it all the days of his life, in order that he learn to fear [before] Adonoy, his God, to guard every word of this Torah and these statutes to fulfill them;
> 20That his pride not increase over his brothers and he does not stray from the commandment right or left; so that the days of his reign are lengthy over his kingdom, he and his sons within Yisroel.

Comment: I wouldn't describe most biblical legal passages as clear or detailed.

Answer (score -2):

Rabbi Lord Sacks zt”l maintained that theocracy was not required for a Jewish state.

See “The Great Partnership” p 130,

> “One of the key biblical projects is to demythologise and
> **secularise** power.” (my emphasis).

See also [here](The Chief Rabbi’s critical ideas-The Jewish Chronicle (thejc.com))

> “From The Politics of Hope through To Heal a Fractured World and
> Future Tense, through his (Rabbi Lord Sacks') articles in broadsheet
> newspapers across the English-speaking world and his television and
> radio broadcasts, the interest in civil and political society as a
> specifically religious concern is central to his work, but in a manner
> that is utterly opposed to the sort of theocracy or fanaticism that
> currently besmirches religion in the eyes of the world.

Comment: I believe Rabbi Sacks meant that in Judaism, the ruler is not a deity, as he was in other nations of that time. And the quote in the Jewish Chronicle is against modern theocracies, not all of them in general.

Comment: @N.T. You're right. So just take the first quote and read around there. It's clear that he thinks democracy is the Jewish way.

Comment: The “democracy” aspect is in regard to the appointment of the King only. But the government itself is a monarchy with a judiciary (the Sanhedrin). They adjudicate cases and interpret the application of the law. The law itself is what G-d gave us via Moshe, our teacher at Mount Sinai. The understanding of the law, meaning the Torah, is the living aspect which evolves through each generation by all those who take possession of the Torah and study it. Like it says, “It is a Tree of Life to those who take hold of it.”